# After blocking ads, how can i redisplay ads in android applications?

Tags: android, ads

A long time ago, I've blocked ads by mistake with a program but now i need ads and i dont remember the name og program. I look for the program, in my phone but there is not a program that can block ads.

I added admob ads to my application but i cannot test its.

How can I redisplay ads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have changed your 'host' file to block ads on all your apps in android. host file is in /system/etc or /etc in android; use filemanager to access the file and edit it on computer. Now to get the original "host" file is your headache. Source :http://hongkiat.com/blog/blocking-ads-in-android/ "2nd Step"

Comment: By deleting the 'hosts' file, I solved the problem. Thank you :)